# Vector3.SmoothDamp() isn't moving the gameObject completely

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I drag the gameObject beyond the screen borders, it comes back towards the center of the scene, but it stops moving right after the middle of the gameObject crosses the margin into the screen.

This screenshot shows the gameObject right after being stopped while moving towards the center of the scene.

[image: Screenshot]

Where's my mistake? How do I make the card move completely to the center of the scene?

```
[SerializeField] private Canvas canvas;
Vector3 offset = Vector3.zero;

[SerializeField] private GameObject cardChoice;
private CanvasGroup cardChoiceCG;

private int resolutionX = Screen.width;
private int resolutionY = Screen.height;

[SerializeField] private float distanceToFadeIn;

[SerializeField] private float smoothTime = 0.25f;
private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;


private void Start() {

    cardChoiceCG = cardChoice.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();
}


private void Update() {

    Vector3 screenPosition = canvas.worldCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(this.transform.position);

    if (screenPosition.x > resolutionX || screenPosition.x < 0f || 
        screenPosition.y > resolutionY || screenPosition.y < 0f) {

        transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, canvas.transform.TransformPoint(Vector3.zero), ref velocity, smoothTime);
    }

    cardChoiceCG.alpha = Math.Abs((1f / distanceToFadeIn) * (screenPosition.x - (resolutionX / 2)));
}

public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData) {

    RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(canvas.transform as RectTransform, eventData.position, canvas.worldCamera, out Vector2 pos);
    offset = transform.position - canvas.transform.TransformPoint(pos);
}


public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {

    RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(canvas.transform as RectTransform, eventData.position, canvas.worldCamera, out Vector2 movePos);
    transform.position = canvas.transform.TransformPoint(movePos) + offset;
}
```

}

Comment: Could you add an empty gameObject into canvas and use it as a target in SmoothDump function maybe problem is canvas itself.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! `transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, canvas.transform.TransformPoint(Vector3.zero), ref velocity, smoothTime);` was inside the if statement, so it only worked while the center of the card was off screen.